# How to convert a string to a complex number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

I'm trying to convert an input string to a float but when I do it I keep getting some kind of error, as shown in the sample below.

```
>>> a = "3 + 3j"
>>> b = complex(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string
```

Comment: Should be: `a="3+3j"`.

Answer (score 15):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#complex):

> Note
>
> When converting from a string, the string must not contain whitespace
>   around the central + or - operator. For example, `complex('1+2j')` is
>   fine, but `complex('1 + 2j')` raises `ValueError`.

Answer (score 9):

Following the answer from [Francisco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1192111/francisco), the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#complex) states that

> When converting from a string, the string must not contain whitespace around the central + or - operator. For example, complex('1+2j') is fine, but complex('1 + 2j') raises ValueError.

Remove all the spaces from the string and you'll get it done, this code works for me:

```
a = "3 + 3j"
a = a.replace(" ", "") # will do nothing if unneeded
b = complex(a)
```

Answer (score 6):

`complex`'s constructor rejects embedded whitespace. Remove it, and it will work just fine:

```
>>> complex(''.join(a.split()))  # Remove all whitespace first
(3+3j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) works like a charm. Accepts spaces (or not) and can multiply etc:

```
>>> eval("2 * 0.033e-3 + 1j * 0.12e-3")
(6.6e-05+0.00012j)
>>> type(eval("2 * 0.033e-3+1j*0.12 * 1e-3"))
<class 'complex'>
```

There could be caveats that I am unaware of but it works for me.

Comment: Eval you have to careful once you move to the case of parsing text from user input or a file rather than just entering your own complex number as a string.

Answer (score 0):

With a dataframe x_df filled with strings that need to be converted. This solution worked for me. It's an asinine workaround, but it works.

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(eval)
x_full = vfunc(x_df.to_numpy())
```